# How to properly escape data for the browser to parse? addslahes() for the browser? 

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been using `addslahes()`.  But this escapes database characters.  However I need to escape HTML characters as in this environment below:

Or a better idea, I plan to not use `document.write()` and simply use `.innerHTML`.  Would I need to escape at all if I don't write to the window?

Currently I use `document.write()` and if I take out `addslashes()`..then the code breaks as the browser reads the next apostrophe as closing the input string.

Is there a similar function to `addslashes()` but for browser data as opposed to database data?

**PHP generated(inside the page:**

```
        <?php 
            $Object = new ObjectMaker();
            $ObjectTweet=$Object->makeTweetSmall();
            $ObjectTweet->pageInsert(); 
        ?>
```

**The function called**

```
public function pageInsert()
{
    $resultArray=$this->DatabaseObject->_pdoQuery('multiple', 'tweet_model');
    $resultAml = MarkTweet::up($resultArray);

    $resultAml = addslashes($resultAml); // this is a hack that does not work / do it correctly 
    $embeddedAml = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(Arc.ViewHTweet('" . $resultAml . "'))</script>";

    Control::send($embeddedAml);
}
```

**HTML/ Embedded Javascript Output**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(Arc.ViewHTweet(

    '1|Test Account|1329782549|1329782546|\\\'||1|Test     
    Account|1329782549|1329782544|\\\\||1|Test 
    Account|1329782549|1329782540|hi||1|Test     
    Account|1329782549|1329781792|\\\'||1|Test 
    Account|1329782549|1329781707|hi\\\\||1|Test      
    Account|1329782549|1329781701|/||1|Test 
    Account|1329782549|1329781675|<a class=\'bookmark_tweet\' target=\'_blank\' href=\'http://bing.com\'>hi\\\\</a>'

))</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use JSON data format as a translation between php and javascript data?

Comment: Your choice ;) I think that printing raw javascript code in php is ugly solution

Comment: I no longer compose html on the server...but still there should be ( or I think there should ) a way to escape html when you want to use it as data instead of as html code or html rendered code ( using special characters ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addslashes is only useful for DB queries.  For browser output, you need encoding:

PHP's htmlspecialchars():

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: This is a completely different approach, you are replacing the special characters with html entities instead of escaping them.

Comment: Yes, why do you want to "escape" characters in the first place?  I'm assuming to avoid mixup in the function call parameter.  htmlspecialchars() will switch them to something the browser can render properly, but since they don't show up as quotes in the js source, the function call will work fine.  (if that's not it, then I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish; is this data that's only being displayed or are you sending it somewhere?)